# Rails 6 secret_key_base vs secret_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6.1

This might be a naive question, but I am new to Ruby and appreciate any guidance.
I am working on upgrading my app to use Rails 6

My secret_token.rb currently has

```
MyApp::Application.config.secret_token = ENV['SECRET_TOKEN'] || SecureRandom.hex(128)
```

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#config-secrets-yml says "Use your existing secret_key_base from the secret_token.rb initializer to set the SECRET_KEY_BASE environment variable for whichever users running the Rails application in production."

I do not see secret_key_base being set anywhere. Is config.secret_key_base just renamed version of config.secret_token, can I just set the ENV['SECRET_TOKEN'] in secrets.yml file like this

```
production:
   secret_key_base: ENV['SECRET_TOKEN']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `secrets.yml` file will not longer be valid in Rails 6. Instead, you will have an encrypted credentials file.

You can create the file with `rails credentials:edit`. You will see an error message with a suggested command based on your editing software. Cut and paste the suggestion.

Here you will store all your keys/tokens/etc.

You access them with `Rails.application.credentials.secret_token` or `Rails.application.credentials.aws[:secret_access_token]`

Based on your comments above, it sounds like you need to change `config.secret_token` to `config.secret_key_base`, and set this equal to your secret_key_base variable like this:

```
YourApp::Application.config.secret_key_base = Rails.application.credentials.dig(Rails.env.to_sym, :secret_key_base)
```

this assumes your `credentials.yml.enc` file has this setup:

```
production:
  secret_key_base: a;sodkfjas;odkjfa;sodkjf

development:
  secret_key_base: pqweiurwoeiurwopeiruowu

aws:
  secret_access_token: mncMXncXMnc>KMXnc>KNc
```